# Callback function not working in my post request

Tags: javascript, express, callback

I have this code with callbacks:

```
function getUserToken(data, callback) {
    var password_sha256 = sha256(data.password);
    getAppById(data.app_id).then(function(res) {
        console.log("app"+res);
            if (!res) {
                console.log("No app");
                callback(err, { meta: {
                    code: 403,
                    error_message: "There are no app with your id!"
                } });
            } else {
                if (res.user_password == password_sha256) {
                    console.log("user found");
                    callback(err, { meta: { code: 200 },
                                    token: password_sha256,
                                    type: 1 });
                    return;
                } else if (res.owner_password == password_sha256) {
                    console.log("owner found");
                    callback(err, { meta: { code: 200 },
                                    token: password_sha256,
                                    type: 0 });
                } else {
                    console.log("user not found");
                    callback(err, { meta: {
                                    code: 403,
                                    error_message: "There are no users with your password!"
                                } });
                }
            }
    });
}
```

I post some data using this function:

```
router.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    db.getUserToken(req.body, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.error) {
            return res.status(403).send(result);
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send(result);
        }
    });
});
```

And then getUserToken found, for example, user, so I have "user found" in console log, but callback function in /api/login not working. Where is my error and how can I fix them?

Comment: In your `getUserToken` function you are calling the `callback` with first argument as `err` - where is this `err` coming from?

Comment: There is no `error` property in `result`

Comment: @blaze-sahlzen, thanks, yep, there are no err, stupid mistake.

Comment: @Andreas, I know, but it works anyway now if user found, then I will replace it for new values.

Comment: There are still quite a few issues with the code..

Comment: there is no err property in result.so first of all you have to pass in callback(null,data) if result is successfull otherwise send callback(true,data).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using callback(err, data) you should use callback(null,data).This will give you required output.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of callback, you can return a Promise, either native or using an external library like [Kris Kowal Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

```
var Q = require('q');

function getUserToken(data) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var password_sha256 = sha256(data.password);
    getAppById(data.app_id).then(function(res) {
        if (!res) {
            deferred.reject("There are no app with your id!");
        } else {
            if (res.user_password == password_sha256) {
                deferred.resolve({
                    token: password_sha256,
                    type: 1
                });
            } else if (res.owner_password == password_sha256) {
                deferred.resolve({
                    token: password_sha256,
                    type: 0
                });
            } else {
                console.log("user not found");
                deferred.reject("There are no users with your password!");
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Then simply process or catch error when you post data

```
router.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    db.getUserToken(req.body)
      .then(function(result) {
          res.status(200).send(result);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          res.status(403).send(error);
      });
});
```

Comment: You don't need `Q` for this as he's already working with Promises. Just some refactoring...

Comment: @Andreas That's exactly what I said, you can use native Promise or a lib like Q